# Making a sldprt to PDB file converter?

Tags: python, parsing

I wanted to create a parser that can read a solidworks file and turn it into a protein data bank file.  This has already been done in a program called DiamondCAD. http://www.zyvex.com/Research/DiamondCAD.html

I waant to make a parser that can parse the data and then visualize it the same way as DiamondCAD.  I have downloaded and opened solidworks files before and they make no sense to me with never before seen symbols and looks like ancient writing.

Does anyone know how a sldprt. file is structured and how it can be parsed into a PDB file? (A  software called VMD converts a PDB to Obj. file so it is proof of concept)

Answer (score -1):

Solidworks can save the .sldprt to many other formats.  .stp may be the easiest to work with, as it is just text.

.sldprt format is proprietary and changes every year.

Good luck!

Comment: Do you have a link or other supporting documentation about the sldprt file format?